# Restore Windows 10 without reseting it if recovery doesn't shows restore points

Tags: windows, windows-10, system-restore

My Windows died after a few days after the last update.

After the last Windows update the System started acting up, like Edge or Ondrive stopped working, the AMD settings (formerly catalyst control center) stopped working but at least the System was running and I was able to work. 
But today it stoped with a bluescreen and since than I'm unable to breath life into it.

The simptoms are: blue scrn with critical process died or black scrn without mouse and only my primary display is on the other two is in standby after the Windows logo dissapears.

When the System boots into recovery and I try to restore it to a prev point there are no restore points, but there should be, because I made one not so long ago. The Windows update if I'm right creates one automaticaly. So why is it empty?

If I restart with boot options, doesn't matter what I choose blue scrn with critical process died.
Boot repair can't repair it probably because its not a boot problem. 
SFC shows problems found but couldn't repair, and in offline mode it doesn't saves the results to CBS log.

So is there anything I can try that isn't the reset Windows option, because I don't have a recent save from my MySQL databases which are about 3GB and of course innoDB.
And obviously I don't want to reinstall all my softwares and reconfigure them.

Oh before you ask every hardware is working ok.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can't use Reset you don't have any options

Comment: I'm really angry because this is the second time when update kills the System. I don't understand why isn't there an option for reset and keep softwares too. If you do an inplace update install with the latest iso than it keeps everything why isn't this a recovery option.

Comment: This happening multiple times indicates a problem with the HDD

Comment: Windows 10 does have a 'Refresh' function, which attempts to reinstall system files without touching AppData/Programdata. Although I'be had mixed results, I recommend giving a Refresh a try, that is however assuming you can't boot from to a USB live OS and back up your data: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4090-refresh-windows-10-a.html

Comment: I know how to refresh Windows, but I didn't wanted. Actually I ended up reinstalling the Windows because Reset stopped at 38% and rolled back, so I had no other way. But thankfully first time in my life I was able to restore my innoDB databases with the raw data files. Now I quickly did a MySQL dump just in case :)